# Upload video to fb not work from android app

Tags: android, facebook, publish-actions

I am trying to upload video to facebook from my android app with following code-

```
    String dataPath = videoPath;
    File mFile = new File(videoPath);
        if(nDialog==null){
            nDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
        }
        if(!nDialog.isShowing()){
            nDialog.setMessage("Posting to your wall...");
            nDialog.setCancelable(false);
            nDialog.show();
        }
        Request.newUploadVideoRequest(session, mFile,new Request.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext,"response"+response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.i("Upload video test0",response.toString());
                nDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
```

but problem is that onCompleted method never got called.
I have also try other code but that was also not working.Please check [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26191889/upload-video-to-facebook-from-my-android-app-fail-with-error-extended-permission?noredirect=1#comment41069785_26191889) also.
Thanks in advance.

Edit:

When i call newUploadVideoRequest method,facebook session has following value -

```
{Session state:OPENED, token:{AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[public_profile, email, contact_email, publish_actions]}, appId:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}
```

Edit:
**OnActivity Result:**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
```

I have try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908413/is-uploading-videos-from-an-sd-card-to-facebook-possible-with-the-facebook-sdk/6924732#6924732) but onCompleted methos returns - `oauthexception code 2500,OAuthException : An active access token must be require`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook Requires extended permission: publish\_actions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12098386/facebook-requires-extended-permission-publish-actions)

Comment: @ṁᾶƔƏň ツ please check mu updated question.

Comment: can I see your `onActivityResult()`

Comment: ya sure,Please check my updated question

Comment: @ṁᾶƔƏň ツ please check my onactivity result method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the publish_actions permission in order to upload a video.

You're also only creating a request, but never executing it. You need to add executeAsync() to your code:

```
 Request.newUploadVideoRequest(session, mFile,new Request.Callback() {
     @Override
     public void onCompleted(Response response) {
         Toast.makeText(mContext,"response"+response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         Log.i("Upload video test0",response.toString());
         nDialog.dismiss();
     }
 }).executeAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks Sir.+1 for your answer.I just forgot to add executeAsync